# Table-tennis table: 乒乓球桌, 乒乓球台 or 乒乓球案子?

Tags: vocabulary

I have found those translations of a "table-tennis table":

> 乒乓球桌
>   乒乓球台
>   乒乓球案子

Searching for pictures of them, all 3 appear to be the same thing. On http://www.mdbg.net/ I only found 乒乓球台 .

Are those words interchangeable? Which is more commonly used?

Comment: 桌 table, 台 platform, 案 wide board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three terms refer to the same thing - table tennis table.

`乒乓球桌` is a commonly used (1.58M results on Google, 2.60M results on Baidu) layman's term.

`乒乓球台` is the technical term (both [Baidu](http://baike.baidu.com/view/1596244.htm) and [Wikipedia](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B9%92%E4%B9%93%E7%90%83) use
 this term) and is commonly used (2.14M results on Google, 4.19M results on Baidu) as well.

`乒乓球案子` is rarely used (0.21M results on Google, 0.13M results on Baidu) from my own personal experience.

When used by itself,

`桌` refers to a table.

`台` refers to a platform or a stage.

`案子` refers to a long table or a plank used as a make-shift table.

If you are discussing about table tennis in general, you can also use `球桌` or `球台` to refer to the table.

Answer (score 4):

The first two are both commonly used. I have never heard of the third one, but a look on google shows usage. I suspect the third one is used more in Northern China, but this is just a guess.

So yes, since they refer to the same thing, you can use them interchangeably, but I'd stick with the first two just to be safe.

Comment: Yes, agree that the third one is quite rarely used.

Comment: The third one is quite commonly used in northern China. In Beijing if I use the former two in casual conversations with my friends they'll be like "wow, why do you sound so formal".

Comment: Thanks @NS.X. I thought so. 案子 used in this way just sounds so Northern to me. The only time I (I was originally from Shanghai) would use 案子 is in the sense of a crime case.

Answer (score 1):

And in Cantonese, it is

兵乓波台

pronounced, roughly, as `BING BUM BOR TOI`, but often the second sound is shortened and quick, to `BING um BOR TOI`.

Comment: 兵乓波台 = bing1 bam1 bo1 toi4 (Yutping)

Comment: Is 兵 (not 乒) the right character here?

Answer (score 1):

As a chinese, I usually call table-tennis table "乒乓球案子", it is correct in some area of China, but it is not formal.In china ,we call table-tennis table "乒乓球台” formally

Answer (score -1):

乒乓球案子 is informal, kind of dialect in some areas.

Comment: Peng, would you mind adding more detail?